# Error: menuCancelAnAlarm cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, sms, alarmmanager

I don't understand this error. please tell me what i should do.

here are my imports:

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

This is where i get the error:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menuCancelAnAlarm: <<-- I get it on this line.
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClassName("com.mbwasi.android.handysmssender", "com.mbwasi.android.handyssmssender.CancelAnAlarmActivity");
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

---

```
Here is my cancelanalarm.xml:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewHr"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Hour"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewHrValue"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewHr"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Hr"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewMins"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewHr"

        android:text="Mins"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewMinsValue"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewMins"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewHrValue"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Mins"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSecs"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewMins"
        android:text="Seconds"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSecsValue"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewSecs"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewMinsValue"
        android:text="Secs"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDay"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewSecs"

        android:text="Day"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDayValue"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewDay"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewSecsValue"
        android:text="Day"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewMonth"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewDay"
        android:text="Month"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewMonthValue"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewMonth"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewDayValue"
        android:text="Month"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewYear"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewMonth"
        android:text="Year"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewYearValue"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewYear"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewMonthValue"
        android:text="Year"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


 </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm new to java and i found this code on google. i'm confused why i get this error when it was working properly on my phone before.

Comment: are you sure you have id `menuCancelAnAlarm` inside menu? case-sensitive

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I checked the XML file but you are not refer the `id name menucancelanalarm` to any of the `TextView id name`.so that you got a error like that.

Check and find it where you have to initialize that id name in Text View.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menucancelanalarm: 
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClassName("com.mbwasi.android.handysmssender", "com.mbwasi.android.handyssmssender.CancelAnAlarmActivity");
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            break;
        }
 return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: @Chix I checked the XML file but you are not refer the `id name menucancelanalarm` to any of the `TextView id name`.so that you got a error like that.

Comment: @Chix that wouldn't refer the xml file name